# Printing <input> elements as displayed on page

Tags: css, forms, printing

I am trying to print a contact form as reference material for a manual.
Is there a way to take a snapshot of a webpage by pressing a print button.

If all else fails i can use print-screen, but its not ideal.

I have tried:

```
@media print
{ 
    input[type="text"] {
    display:block;
    }
}
```

Any clean ways of doing this?

Comment: is it just whitespace where the input should be?  Could of course use print screen button to get the page as is...

Comment: yeah, just whitespace. print-screen isn't what i'm looking for. i'll amend the question. Thanks for reply MikeM

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618368/how-to-capture-the-screen-using-javascript